# How to take Blast data and create a 3d plot to visualize a swing

Tags: r, plotly

Blast uses metrics that aren't very intuitive to create a 3d graph with so i was wondering if there was a way to take this data and create a 3d plot to visualize the swing path.

If anyone is able to help i can send a blast data sample along with documentation for the blast data.

I have tried looking at the data points but i cannot even figure out how to get a single x,y,z point.

Comment: Google suggests: https://plotly.com/r/3d-scatter-plots/

Comment: It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample code you've attempted, any errors/warnings received, what type of output or outcome you expect, and sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).